# How to import material_ui

Tags: python, kivy, material-ui

I recently installed material_ui using pip. I wish to be able to import and use the flatui for my kivy app but I can't seem to figure out how to import it correctly.
After installing this was the code I used to try and import

```
from material_ui.flatui.flatui import FloatingAction
```

This just returns

```
ImportError: No module named material_ui.flatui.flatui
```

This is kind of confusing because I checked in my sites-packages and the folder material_ui is there.
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions as to what could be wrong:

1- check if material_ui is on in a path directory (get the list of path directories using `sys.path`)

2- `from material_ui.flatui.flatui import FloatingAction` could mean two things:

1. Import the module (.py file) at material_ui\flatui\flatui\FloatingAction.py
2. or import the class or function or variable named FloatingAction in the module material_ui\flatui\flatui.py (the error raised suggest that this is what python is trying to do but it doesn't find the file)

So check if either of those files exists, and if the access path is correct (directory names), and, in the second case, if flatui.py does define `FloatingAction`

Comment: Hi. Turns out you were right. Python didn't know that the folder was a package. There was no __init__.py file in the material_ui folder. Hence the import was failing. I had to add __init__.py myself for the import to work.  Thanks